# What is the best way to tell a new user that they can accept an answer if they think it answers their question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have noted that a new user has asked a number of questions (about 12-13) over the last week. Some of them have had (in my own opinion) some very insightful and acceptable answers. In all cases the answers have received up-votes but as of yet the OP has yet to accept any answer on any of their questions.

I'm not sure if the user knows that they can accept an answer as academia stakexchange is their only stackexchange account and it appears from their badges that they have not read the about page.

As my question title suggests, should the OP be told (maybe by way of comment and a link to the about page) that it is appropriate that they can accept an answer if they think it answers their question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed before on SE meta (links at the end).

The consensus there seems to be: if it seems that a new user does not know about accepting answers, it's appropriate to post a *polite* comment on the question saying something like:

> Welcome to **Academia.SE**. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation

(this sample comment is from [Informing new users of how to accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers))

Obviously, being rude to new users is not helpful. Neither is nagging users who obviously know about accepting answers to improve their accept rate.

Discussions on SE meta:

- [Informing new users of how to accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers)
- [Helping users accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199214/helping-users-accept-answers)
- [How to educate new users about accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145987/how-to-educate-new-users-about-accepting-answers)
- [How to tell new users with 0% accept rate to improve it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/how-to-tell-new-users-with-0-accept-rate-to-improve-it)
- [Stop nagging new users about their accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95452/stop-nagging-new-users-about-their-accept-rate)